# Copy line in text file and add modified line to the end of line in same file

Tags: linux, sed, grep, paste

I would like to copy line in text file edit it on the fly to replace all / to | and paste in on the same line in the same line.

I have the first line in the text file:

```
http://webpage.com/(name-never-changes)/aCcboeasdfdRD/asdfasdft21.jpg
```

Copy text between (name-never-changes) and .jpg

```
/aCcboeasdfdRD/asdfasdft21
```

Change to / to |

```
|aCcboeasdfdRD|asdfasdft21
```

And add to the end of the same line where URL is, with a separator
the separator can be text or number or special character

```
http://webpage.com/(name-never-changes)/aCcboeasdfdRD/asdfasdft21.jpg  (separator)  |aCcboeasdfdRD|asdfasdft21
```

And this should work with multiple text files with different URLs

I can't create new files and merge them this should be on the fly because the name of text files are different and I don't know filenames

Comment: separator can be text or number or special character

Comment: will the URL always have 4 fields?

Comment: url have always 4 fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk -F '[/.]' '{print $0" (separator) |"$(NF-2)"|"$(NF-1)}' file

http://webpage.com/(name-never-changes)/aCcboeasdfdRD/asdfasdft21.jpg (saperatot) |aCcboeasdfdRD|asdfasdft21
```

- `/.` two field separators
- `$0` to print the complete line
- `$(NF-2) $(NF-1)` the third and second fields from the end

if you want to save in the file

**Option 1**: (if it has few lines)

```
echo "`awk -F '[/.]' '{print $0" (separator) |"$(NF-2)"|"$(NF-1)}' file`" > file
```

**Option 2**: (if it is a large file)

```
 awk -F '[/.]' '{print $0" (separator) |"$(NF-2)"|"$(NF-1)}' file > tempFile ; mv tempFile file
```

For multiple files in a folder:

```
cd /path/to/dir
for file in `ls`
do
    echo "`awk -F '[/.]' '{print $0" (separator) |"$(NF-2)"|"$(NF-1)}' $file`" > $file
done
```

Comment: use `for` loop.

Comment: What happens if file contains empty line at end? This script dont gonna print in one line only print at second line, how i can deleted second empty line and print in one line

Comment: @unknown valid point!! we can validate by `NF>2`

Comment: source is one line with text which i wanna cpy at the end of same line second line is empty thats why this script print at second line not on same line do You know script to deleted that second line before use script? Im a noob and i dont know what is vaild point

Comment: @unknown yes, try the same code with `NF>1` like `awk -F '[/.]' 'NF>1{print....`

Comment: @unknown cool...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a `sed` solution:

```
sed 'h; s@^[^/]*//[^/]*/[^/]*/@  (separator)  |@; s@/@|@g; s/\.jpg$//; x; G; s/\n//'
```

Step by step:

- `h` copies the current line from the “pattern space” to the “hold space”.
- `s@^[^/]*//[^/]*/[^/]*/@  (separator)  |@` is a **s**ubstitute command
  using `@` as the delimiter. 
  It replaces

  ```
  stuff//stuff/stuff/
  ```

  (i.e., `http://example.com/(top-level-directory)/`)
  with   `(separator)  |`.
  You could do
  `s@^http//example.com/(top-level-directory)/@  (separator)  |@`
  if you wanted to.
- `s@/@|@g` is also a **s**ubstitute command using `@` as the delimiter. 
  It replaces all remaining `/` characters in the line with `|` characters. 
  If you’re sure that there will be only one
  (between *`(second-level-directory)`* and *`(filename)`*),
  you can leave off the `g`.
- `s/\.jpg$//` obviously removes the `.jpg` extension from the end of the line. 
  (If you don’t know what the extension is,
  you could do something like `s/\.[^.]*$//` instead.)
- `x` exchanges the pattern space and the hold space,
  so the original line is now back in the pattern space, and the

  ```
    (separator)  |(second-level-directory)|(filename)
  ```

  that we just built
  is in the hold space.
- `G` **g**ets the contents of the hold space
  and appends it to the pattern space (injecting a newline between them).
- `s/\n//` removes that newline.

This will pass blank lines through as blank lines. 
Other lines will be mangled.

If you want to edit file(s) in place, just pass `sed` the `-i` option
(or `-i.bak`, if desired or required on your system).